# Check sentence by regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a sentence like "Hello world." Check a sentence that it begins with a capital letter and ends with a period(dot).
I've written my regex, but it doesn't work.

```
 "^\\p{Upper}$\\."
```

What's wrong in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^\\p{Upper}.*\\.$
```

Guess you meant this.`^\\p{Upper}$\\.` is incorrect as `$` match end of string.And you want a `.` before it not after.